# Google Firebase Cloud Messaging not in ca_root_nss?

Tags: ssl-certificate, freebsd, certificate-authority, curl, google

We are trying to migrate our push services to Google Firebase Cloud Messaging.
On the development machines (that run linux) everything is fine, but in the integration system (which runs on FreeBSD like the rest of the productive Systems) there is a ssl error which is strange.

On Linux I can "curl https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" and get a propper response but in FreeBSD it says:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

and "fetch https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" responds with:

```
Certificate verification failed for /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
34380949368:error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed:/usr/src/secure/lib/libssl/../../../crypto/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1180:
fetch: https://fcm.googleapis.com: Authentication error
```

the ca_root_nss file is updated and pkg info ca_root_nss says:

```
ca_root_nss-3.27.1
Name           : ca_root_nss
Version        : 3.27.1
Installed on   : Fri Nov 11 15:54:47 2016 CET
Origin         : security/ca_root_nss
Architecture   : freebsd:10:*
Prefix         : /usr/local
Categories     : security
Licenses       : MPL
Maintainer     : ports-secteam@FreeBSD.org
WWW            : UNKNOWN
Comment        : Root certificate bundle from the Mozilla Project
Options        :
        ETCSYMLINK     : on
Annotations    :
        repo_type      : binary
        repository     : FreeBSD
Flat size      : 896KiB
Description    :
Root certificates from certificate authorities included in the Mozilla
NSS library and thus in Firefox and Thunderbird.

This port directly tracks the version of NSS in the security/nss port.
```

Can it be that the Google Firebase Server certificates are missing in the ca_root_nns database used by FreeBSD?

What can I do to import the propper certificate chain?

Comment: GeoTrust certificate should be included in ca_root_nss, try to run `fetch -v --ca-cert=/etc/ssl/cert.pem https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`